# How Rerender component NextJS with changing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, next.js

I have an app that sends Images.

So at the first render, I have all the images shown in the frontend.

Then I send all the images in batch to x person.

And what I'm trying to do, is each time an image is sent, I want it to be deleted from the frontend.

So the client can see a kind of countdown of the images being sent and left.

I'm sending the setter of the useState to the backend, but each time it's being used isn't it supposed to refresh ?

I tried to put a button to see if the code works and yes it works fine, each time I click on it, its rerenders the images left correctly, does kind of refresh when I get the state I guess.

But how to do it automatically, refreshes each time an image is sent.

In the frontend where I display the images I did like so :

```
export default function Home() {

    const [imageLinks, setImageLinks] = useState([""])



    //Getting the image links set them to state and display them in the browser

    const getImageLinks = async (cids) => {
        cids.forEach((link) => {
            let CIDImages = axios.get('https://ipfs.io/' + link)
                .then(linkMetadata => {
                    let rawLinks = linkMetadata.data.image
                    let correctFormatLink = rawLinks.slice(7);
                    setImageLinks(oldArray => [...oldArray, correctFormatLink]);
                })
        })
    }



    //Images component

     const images = () => {
        return (
            <>
                {
                    imageLinks.map((link, index) => {
                        return <img src={`https://ipfs.io/ipfs/${link}`} alt="" key={index}/>;
                    }
                )}
            </>
        )
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        images()
    }, [imageLinks, setImageLinks])


return (
            {
               images()
            }
    )
}
```

Then where I have my functions in a separate file :

```
export async function mint(setImageLinks, imageLinks, cids) {


    //Sending images

    let imageTower = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < cids.length; i++) {
        imageTower[i] = await tokenMinterFcn(cids[i])
        let imageLink = await axios.get('https://ipfs.infura.io' + cids[i])
            .then(linkMetadata => {
                //Correct formay of the link
                let rawLinks = linkMetadata.data.image
                let correctFormatLink = rawLinks.slice(7);

                // Filter to remove the link from imageLinks array
                imageLinks.filter(imageLink => {
                    if (imageLink === correctFormatLink) {
                        imageLinks.splice(imageLinks.indexOf(imageLink), 1)
                    }
                })
                setImageLinks(imageLinks);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't posted full code. Where is `useState` here?

Comment: @AleksaRistic just added in the code to show. I refactored most of the code to simplify. Sorry

Comment: Do you have any `useEffect` inside `Home` class?

Comment: @AleksaRistic yes just under  my const images I have it, to render it at the first load :      useEffect(() => {
        images()
    }, [imageLinks, setImageLinks])

Comment: I guessed. If you want me to help you you need to post full class.